# REFrostedViewController and iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8

I'm not sure if anyone has a fix for this but I've been trying to use this library I have everything setup but can't seem to achieve the blur like in the demo. I have navigation setup and working correctly but I cannot set a blur or blur tint color. I'm able to customize direction and a couple other properties but the blur does not seem to be working. The only thing I can think of is that this does not work for iOS 8. Here is my RootViewController's `awakeFromNib`:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.contentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"homeController"];
    self.menuViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"sideMenuController"];
    self.liveBlur = NO;
    self.liveBlurBackgroundStyle = REFrostedViewControllerLiveBackgroundStyleLight;
    self.blurRadius = 60;
    self.blurTintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:45/255.0 green:55/255.0 blue:56/255.0 alpha:0.6];
 }
```

Comment: you should look at the original apples blur:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/84043/ios-8-visual-effects-tutorial

Comment: @gronzzz thank you for pointing out that tutorial. I was trying to avoid reinventing the wheel in a manner of speaking if I could find an already developed library, but none of the behavior seems to be what I need. If I can't find a solution I might just have to write one for my needs

Answer (score 1):

If you need just iOS8 blur you can use this code. There you are creating VisualEffectView with blur effect and then set frame to this view.

```
    UIVisualEffect *effect;
    effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleDark];
//    effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleLight];
//    effect = [UIBlurEffect effectWithStyle:UIBlurEffectStyleExtraLight];

    UIVisualEffectView *blurEffectView = [[UIVisualEffectView alloc] initWithEffect:effect];
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:self.blurEffectView];
```

But you can also use UIImage+ImageEffects apples library for that case.

**UPDATE**

That's a result: blur on view controller and effected UILabel on top.

[image]

Comment: This would add blur but would it show the controller underneath? I'm trying to achieve the same behavior this library had for iOS 7 where it blurs the view controller that it is sitting on top when the menu comes out

Comment: it will blurs view of controller, on which you will make addSubview. in fact you have blurs uiview, that you can add everywhere you want. i'm attached screenshot